# Bluetooth transmitter headphone jack soldering points

Tags: pcb, audio, soldering, bluetooth, transmitter

I am in the process of modding a 7th gen iPod.

I have purchased a Bluetooth transmitter/receiver from AliExpress (VALORO 2 IN 1 transmitter) andtaken the PCB out. Noe I am unsure what points to solder from to the actual iPod headphone jack.

The headphone jack on the right is the transmitter, and that I will be using the soldering points to solder to the audio of the iPod.

I cannot seem to find the right, left and ground points on the board. Nothing is labeled on the PCB.

Does anyone have experience with soldering Bluetooth transmitters?

[image]

Comment: look at the pattern of components on the board ... it is not difficult to guess which are the L and R

Comment: I'm new to soldering. My guess would be ground, right, left from top to bottom. Is that correct?

Comment: that's a very good guess ... btw: soldering is the act of attaching components with solder... it has nothing to do with identifying  pins ... it has nothing to do with Bluetooth modules, which you seem to imply

Comment: This isn't about bluetooth transmitters or soldering. It is about determining the pinout of a connector. And these connectors have more than 3 pins so without a multimeter and plug for measuring the pinout it will be difficult to guess which is which.

Comment: Do an operational test. Turn on the device you’re going to receive the BT audio, activate and pair this transmitter, then touch the connector points one at a time with a small screwdriver ( put your finger on the metal part of the screwdriver too). You should hear hum from one channel when you touch its pin on the connector. You may have to plug a cable into the connector if there’s an internal switch; just leave the other end disconnected.